# Why are my edits pending so long in the queue?

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, suggested-edits

When I edit a post that has been pending for a long time. Therefore I cannot edit and post the first one does not prevail. Is there is no solution for this?

Comment: Wait longer? It's a weekend, many people do other things. It's all volunteer driven. The other option is to gain enough reputation you no longer need to suggest edits. At 2k you can just edit.

Comment: And you have 5 pending edits waiting, out of 31 you suggested today. There are 180 other edits waiting too, you'll just have to wait your turn.

Comment: You should also think about whether your changes really make sense to do below 2k. Also your comments are very very bad, you just leave "I think this is better statement for your question." which absolutely doesn't help to identify what you did.

Comment: You can always edit your own questions. And that **is** necessary: begging, like ["Please help me."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584333/switch-button-perform-hide-splash-screen), has no place in good posts on [so].

Answer (score 4):

You can have at most [5 pending suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232). They need to be reviewed, and the queue is already quite full (176 entries).

The only solution is to gather enough reputation ([2000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)) to edit posts:

> That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit *anything* in the system without it going through peer review.

Comment: "The only solution is to gather enough reputation" Or you can skip the queue by asking the edited post's author to review your edit.

Comment: @dorukayhan the author gets notified *automatically* - I don't see the point in asking them (via a comment, I presume).